# Java boolean setter with "has" prefix according to naming convention

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Simple question but I can't understand.

Example with `is` prefix:

```
private boolean active;

public boolean isActive(){...};//getter

public boolean setActive(boolean b){...};//setter
```

But I don't understand how to do setter with `has` prefix

```
private boolean hasChildren;

public boolean hasChildren(){...};//getter

public boolean  ?(boolean b){...}//setter
```

Comment: `setHasChildren` ? It is not that important as long as it is semantically clear...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem in your case is not only finding an appropriate name for the setter. It is also that **your getter does not follow the conventions**!

The [specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/spec-136004.html) and the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) are very clear on this:

- The setter for a property should be prefixed with `set`
- The getter for a non-boolean property should be prefixed with `get`
- The getter for a boolean property should be prefixed with `is`

And it is important to follow these conventions, because otherwise, many automatic (reflection-based) tools will no longer work as expected (e.g. [Introspectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html)).

---

Grammar aside, there are several options for solving this. In a comment, it was suggested to call the property `isParent`, although then, strictly speaking, the accessor would have to be called `isIsParent`...

So I'd suggest to simply call the property something like `havingChildren` or `owningChildren`, and offer the corresponding accessor methods like `isHavingChildren`/`setHavingChildren`, or
`isOwningChildren`/`setOwningChildren`, respectively.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the specification and tutorial do not say the getter for a boolean property _should_ be prefixed with "is"; it states that it is _allowed_ to use this format. Quoted from the specification: "This “is<PropertyName>” method may be provided instead of a “get<PropertyName>” method, or it may be provided in addition to a “get<PropertyName>” method."

Answer (score 3):

According to the [JavaBeans Specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/spec-136004.html) (section 8.3.2) accessor methods for a boolean field `foo` are `isFoo()` and `setFoo(boolean)` accordingly.

Your case would be a accessor pair `isHasChildren()`/`setHasChildren()`.

As a suggestion, your should consider renaming of the field into `boolean childrenPresent;`, which would, according to the spec, be derived into `isChildrenPresent()` and `setChildrenPresent()`.

Comment: @Waldheinz good! But if we are going this far, it could actually, instead of a property of the class, be the result of something like, given `Collection children;`, `return children.isEmpty();` and never need to be set directly (instead, come from additions to the Collection) ;) I edited the suggestion based on your comment.

Comment: @Waldheinz actually, I don't like your idea that much: `parent` would indicate to me a reference to other object (think of a tree). But I might be a bit too graph biased :)

Answer (score 0):

You can safely go for `setHasChildren` as it is totally clear. Nevertheless if you are storing more information about the children, it could change the answer.

For example, if you need to store the children, only the setter would make sense and the children would be represented by a collection :

```
// no hasChildren attribute
private Collection<ChildClass> children;
public boolean hasChildren(){ return !children.isEmpty(); };
// no setter
```

Another example, if you are storing the number of children :

```
// no hasChildren attribute
private int childrenCount;
public boolean hasChildren(){ return childrenCount > 0 };
// no setter
```

Answer (score 0):

For Boolean you can use `is` as a prefix in getter , or you can also use 
`get` as a prefix

```
public boolean isHasChildern();//getter
public boolean getHasChilder();//getter
public boolean setHasChildren(boolean active);//setter
```

Answer (score 0):

hasChildren is inspecting the state of an object and as such I wouldn't usually expect a setter method.

I would expect that if you had no children (hasChildren() == false) and then were to addChild(Whatever) then the next time you call hasChildren, it would return true.

By attempting to manipulate that behaviour manually, you're breaking encapsulation and the Law of Demeter as your calling program should know about its owned objects, but not the implementation of its objects own objects. I hope that makes some sense.

To make a crude analogy, you could ask a lady if she's with child and she will (hopefully) report her status (or start crying because you just called her "large). If false, you could proceed to make her pregnant (subject to consent of course), you wouldn't just cram a baby up there and say "there, you're pregnant now".

Answer (score 0):

If it's really as in your code, where you have a `boolean` for this, go ahead and use `setHasChildren`.

Usually, "has" sorts of attributes don't have simple setters because they're usually reporting a state that isn't backed by a simple boolean, e.g.:

```
private List<Child> children;
// ...
public boolean hasChildren() {
    return children.size() > 0;
}
// ...
public void addChild(Child c) {
    // ...
}
```

But when that's not the case, `setHasXyz` is fine.

Answer (score -1):

When we are talking about hasChildren , hasAttributes , we are talking about whether there is any collections attached to it. Like children can be many , eg can be a list or a map whereas incase of isActive we are just denoting a single property value.
You can set the value setHasChildren. But then I think naming convention is for convenience of understanding.